# Do physics libraries have things I might be able to use for geometry culling?

Tags: c++, physics, partitioning

I always hear the relationship between collision detection and the different space partitioning techniques. Do any physics libraries contain common data structures like maybe a frustum class or anything that would make it easier to implement octrees, quadtrees, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/), the Computational Geometry Algorithms Library. You can find an overview of what it offers in [this list of packages](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/packages.html). I'm not sure about frustum, quadtrees or octrees specifically, but it does have spatial indexing implementations.